# Apache Camel data types between components

Tags: java, apache-camel

### I could not find any documentation around this on Apache Camel website.

How and what types are supported in the communication between the components in **Apache Camel**. I would like to understand the magic that happens inside it. Because the doc just says you consume data from a file system or FTP, a message from JMS, SQL data and tons of other possibilities and send them to a producer that magically seems to accept anything and output to tons of possibilities also.

- Do they wrote converters for all to all types in the framework?

And I wonder the same question around enriches. All this connectors seem extremely flexible and I could not find any reference to what supports what in there. I'm willing to write a component for a system and I couldn't find a good way to do it.

- Do I have to write converters for all possible types that can come?

I have seen that camel works with the `Exchange` class and it uses it to send back and forth the messages between components. It is pretty vague in my mind how the components deal with different possible message types.

Comment: Camel has a couple of [built-in converters](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/converter) which cover already a vast number of formats. If you need more specialized ones (i.e. like conversion of messages between Apache CXF and Camel) the component can specify [its own converters](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/components/camel-cxf/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/cxf/converter) as well

Comment: Don't forget to declare these custom converters in the [`META-INF` section of the resources](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/components/camel-cxf/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org/apache/camel) though otherwise Camel does not pick them up by default and hence will not be able to convert messages appropriately

Comment: @RomanVottner so technically even the existing components are not all compatible with each other right?

Comment: A converter is just a mapping between two (or multiple) formats. How should Camel know how to process a certain data format into an other if it wasn't instructed. You can of course always fall back to one of the default ones contained in camel-core (i.e. InputStream or byte[])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to take a look at "Camel in Action" book by Claus Ibsen and Jonathan Anstey. I used to have questions like those. They are perfectly answered there. Chapter 11.3 will guide you through creating your own component. Also, you can check out this github [link](https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction/tree/master/chapter11/custom) to start with. It has an example of how to create your own component.

Camel may to know what types you pass in the message body, so it offers you multiple ways to transform the payload, starting from creating a processor for transformation, to using a java DSL `transform` method which accepts `Expression`.

Just be ready to handle a case, when an unknown object is consumed. Don't worry about all the incoming objects.
It all depends how the Consumers are implemented.

Comment: I have already gone through the steps of creating a component and I have done some initial work around the one I want to create the goes beyond sending strings. But without knowing this answers I might make some wrong assumptions...

Comment: It depends on what possible cases you may have. What are you consuming? files? Objects?

Comment: I will be consuming files with optional custom metadata in it... The way I added the metadata was through the Attachments in the Exchange object. I don't know if its the correct approach though

Comment: Yes, that will do, but keep in mind, that if you decide at some point in route, to do some processing, and put the result in "out" message, don't forget to move all the headers and attachments from "in" message as well, since they are not moved automatically.

Comment: if I don't set the out, will it forward everything by default? Or the next endpoint would receive an empty message?

Comment: If you do some processing and set the updated body in "in" message and will not touch the "out" one. It would automatically move the body, headers and attachments to "out" by default.